# Can't get MySQL Community Server to Start from Command prompt or Netbeans IDE

Tags: mysql, windows, netbeans-7

I have installed Netbeans 7 on my Windows 7. In addition, the MySQL Community Server 5.6.12
 is installed with the MSI installer on thesame 7 PC.

The MySQL server is integrated with the Netbeans IDE. However , it is not possible to start or stop the MySQL server from the command prompt or the Netbeans IDE.

I am only able to start or stop the server from the Windows 7 services tool.
Also , it is difficult running SQL queries from the Netbeans IDE even though it shows there is connection with the MySQL server.

I have added the my.ini file to the installed directory of the MySQL server , that is :

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6
```

below is the my.ini file :

```
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-configuration-defaults.html
# *** DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE. It's a template which will be copied to the
# *** default location during install, and will be replaced if you
# *** upgrade to a newer version of MySQL.

[mysqld]

# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M

# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin

# These are commonly set, remove the # and set as required.
# basedir = .....
# datadir = .....
port = 3306
# server_id = .....


# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M 

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

Any suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: Your question is off-topic because it not related to a programming problem. It is an administration task. You might find help at [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/). You will be asked which command you tried to start the server, as well as any error message that you may receive from the prompt, or that you can find in the server logs.

Comment: thanks for the response . By he way what is ServerFault

Comment: Just click the link in my previous comment :) It is a sister site of StackOverflow, lead by the same team. Just the topic is different. Please note I am not sure this question is on-topic at ServerFault. You might want to check their help page too.